# Formally writing the Bertrand's paradox in logic?

Tags: probability, logic, paradoxes

I was trying to formalise the different methods of calculating probability in  [bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) in logic, this is my attempt:
\begin{align}
\Phi \equiv x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
\Psi(m,c) \equiv y = mx + c\\
\chi(m,c) \equiv \exists x \exists y. \Phi \land\Psi(m,c) \\
\mu(m,c) \equiv \chi(m,c) \land \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}>0.5 \right)
\end{align}
I think what we need to evaluate is :
$$ \Pr(\mu(m,c)|\chi(m,c))$$
Where $(m,c)$ are uniformly distributed (don't worry if you think evaluating this probability is meaningless (or not defined), I just want to formalise it ).

I realised that what I am modelling is none of the three methods.

Can anyone help me with formalising the three methods in this way ?